# Usage of I believe in a B2B environment

Tags: word-choice, formality, diction

I am a quality analyst for an enterprise account that deals with clients directly meaning we are advised to use formal language at all times when speaking to customers. I would like to confirm if it is a diction error and if it is considered informal to use I believe when verifying information. Thanks!

Examples:

I believe that I am speaking with...
I believe you want to activate your license...
I believe your company name is...

Comment: diction is pronunciation. No, of course it isn't informal. I believe, I think etc. are standard English. Informal might be: Are ya John? But, I believe sounds almost too formal. I would leave out the I believe. Is this Mr. Smith I am speaking to? Would you like to activate your license?

Comment: I've never heard of such a concept. Where did you get the idea from? I'm not sure it's exactly On Topic to ask about the suitability of some arbitrarily selected usage in the absence of any suggestion that it *might* not be considered appropriate.

Comment: Is this written or spoken? Is this between native speakers, or with non-native speakers, or a mix?

Comment: [*She is somewhat younger than yourself, Sire, but **I believe** Antigone was of that age when you met her, and a finer woman has never walked the earth.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Sire%2C+but+I+believe+Antigone%22) That looks pretty "formal" to me.

Comment: @Lambie - I looked up *diction*: "the choice and use of words and phrases in speech or writing."  The tag looks okay to me.

Comment: Maybe http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ would be a good place to ask about this.  I don't have much experience with that site but it might be worth a try.  Reading between the lines, I sense that someone let you know, in perhaps a tactless way, that your "I believe that" was getting on their nerves.  If so, I have no opinion about that; but what you might want to do is rewrite your question on this site to ask for alternative ways of expressing the idea.  Then you could try out your new repertoire at work, and see which ones seem to go over best.  (It's hard to give you an absolute formula.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is a parameter set by our Senior Analysts. I actually want to know as well what is wrong with using this so I can justify it to my subordinates since I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Mitch this is for spoken english. It's a mix of native and non-native speakers since we deal with almost everyone across the world.

Comment: @Maia Kurenai: I don't understand that. Are you saying that one of your "Senior Analysts" claims it would be somehow "inappropriate" to use the words ***I believe** [X is true]* in a "business-oriented" conversation? Did they give any ***evidence*** for such a strange claim?

Comment: @FumbleFingers According to them, I believe is subjective and almost synonymous to I think. Since agents are presented with facts, they should sound sure about what they are saying.

Comment: Maia, you should add that nuance to your OP so that it might convince people to vote to reopen. So not only are you interested in the register (the formality or context) but also in the pragmatics of using it or not). TL;DR register: it means the same thing as 'I think' but is more formal; pragmatics: they are 'weasel words', used to weaken a statement so that if you turn out to be wrong, you can claim that you only said that you -thought- so but weren't sure.

Comment: A company might decide to forbid its analysts to use "I believe" for various reasons. The likeliest of these is that the company wants all statements to be presented as standing on a foundation of fact rather than on one of belief or opinion. To avoid the offending wording in the examples you give, you might reframe the statements as "Am I speaking with...?" "I understand that you want to activate your license..." "Your company name appears to be..." This is not a matter of formality but of identifying what things objectively seem to be, rather than what you believe them to be.

Comment: @aparente001 Good for you. What is being discussed here (informal or formal) does not concern diction.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using 'I believe...' in a formal business discussion, although it would sound a little forced to use it repeatedly.
The 'formality' required would be far more about the mode of address and being polite. So you would not be expected to open a discussion with 'Hi there, Mike. I believe you want to open an account.' You would address the person by their full name and title - e.g. Mr Michael Mouse. It's also considered more polite to say 'you would like to' instead of 'you want to'.

For example, a typical business discussion over the phone might go like this:
Good morning, my name is Maia Kerenai from the XYZ company. Am I speaking to Mr Michael Mouse?. I believe you recently contacted us and I understand you would like to activate your license.
May I confirm that your company name is Soft Toys limited?

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "I understand that..." or "My understanding is that ...".  "Understand" is less likely to carry a connotation of religion or mysticism, and doesn't seem to be "talking down" to the correspondent as much as "believe" does.